# Looking for a closed form expression of $\prod_{n=1}^{m}(n!)^n$ or $\prod_{n=1}^{m}n^{-n^2}$

Tags: products

I'm working on some math in my spare time and wanted to see if it were possible to find $\prod_{n=1}^{m}(n!)^n$ as a closed form expression.

I was able to work through it to get it down to $$\prod_{n=1}^{m}(n!)^n = \prod_{n=1}^{m}(n)^{1/2(m^2+m+n-n^2)}.$$

This can go further to $$(m!^{(m+m^2)} H(m)\prod_{n=1}^{m}n^{-n^2})^{1/2},$$ where $H(m)$ is the hyperfactorial of $m$.

But I'm still unable to figure out a closed form of $\prod_{n=1}^{m}n^{-n^2}$. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It's not clear why we'd expect such a closed formula.

Comment: If you define a more generalized Hyperfactorial: $$H(m,k)=\prod_{n=1}^m n^{n^k},$$ then $H(n,1)$ is the original Hyperfactorial, and you get: $$\sqrt{\frac{m!^{m+m^2} H(m,1)}{H(m,2)}}$$ But that is sort of a hack. Essentially, even the original hyperfactorial is a hack - it is just adding a closed form for something that doesn't have a closed formula.

Comment: Are you defining the original hyperfactorial as what you wrote? Edit: Nevermind I see what you are saying

Comment: You get [this zeta expression](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+n%5Ek+log%28n%29+from+n%3D1+to+r) instead of the “hyperfactorial”. The derivative in the expression is not a closed form though.